# Ruby: 'case true' when does it block loop?

Tags: ruby

There is piece of code

```
 A = "am"
    F = "fm"
    def fmam(n)
        return if n == 0
        loopy(n - 1)
        case true
        when n % 15 == 0
            puts B + L
        when n % 5 == 0
            puts L
        when n % 3 == 0
            puts B
        else
            puts n
        end
    end
    fmam(20)
```

in this code what does `case true`  do it this code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`case` has two forms.  The form you're using compares the "target" after the `case` keyword ( `true` in this case) with each comparison (the part after each `when` keyword) using the `===` operator.  You end up with a series of boolean expressions and execute the code for the first one that evaluates to `true`.  As such, it's redundant and a bit confusing.  It would be better to remove the `true` and use the second form of `case`:

```
    case
    when n % 15 == 0
        puts B + L
    when n % 5 == 0
        puts L
    when n % 3 == 0
        puts B
    else
        puts n
    end
```

This does the same thing but is clearer.

Answer (score 3):

[`tutorialspoint`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_if_else.htm) :- says

```
case expression
[when expression [, expression ...] [then]
   code ]...
[else
   code ]
end
```

Compares the `expression` specified by `case` and that specified by when using the `===` operator and executes the code of the `when` clause that matches.

saying that look below:

```
A = "am"
F = "fm"
L = "dd"
B = 'aa'
def fmam(n)
    return if n == 0

    case true
    when n % 15 == 0
        puts B + L
    when n % 5 == 0 # this evaluates to true first, which then matched with true value mentioned in the case statement.
        puts L
    when n % 3 == 0
        puts B
    else
        puts n
    end
end
fmam(20) #=> dd
```

Now look at the below code:

```
A = "am"
F = "fm"
L = "dd"
B = 'aa'
def fmam(n)
    return if n == 0

    case false
    when n % 25 == 0 # this evaluates to false first, which then matched with false value mentioned in the case statement.
        puts B + L
    when n % 5 == 0
        puts L
    when n % 3 == 0
        puts B
    else
        puts n
    end
end
fmam(30) #=> aadd
```

Answer (score 0):

You could refactor the case statement to

```
msg = case 0
when n % 15
  B + L
when n % 5
  L
when n % 3
  B
else
  n
end
puts msg
```